# Variable inside a class is not defined NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I am developing an application to send emails with nodeJs 6.9 and express 4.
I am also using a library called powerdrill which is the library that calls Mandrill APIs.

I am trying to use the message variable which is the variable that use the powerdrill library to create the object and send the email. I am using this variable inside a method but is throwing an error.

```
'use strict';    
var config = require('config'),
    queries = require('api/queries'),
    Message = require('powerdrill').Message;
    

class MandrillService{
    
    constructor(config, Message) {
        this.config = config;
        this.Message = Message;
    }

    welcome(){
        //console.log(req.body);
        message = new Message();
        message.apiKey(config.mandrillKey)
          .subject('Welcom')
          .template('welcome-email')
          .from(config.mandrilEmail)
          .to('david@gmail.com')
          .tag('complex')
          .globalMergeVar('VERIFY_EMAIL','link')
          .send(function(err, resp) {
          });
    }
}

module.exports = new MandrillService(config);
```

error:

```
Unhandled rejection ReferenceError: message is not defined
        at MandrillService.welcome (/home/user/platform/services/mandrillService.js:28:17)
        at /home/user/platform/services/notificationService.js:222:22
        at Promise._execute (/home/user//platform/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/debuggability.js:303:9)
        at Promise._resolveFromExecutor (/home/user/platform/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:483:18)
```

**I don´t know what is the behavior inside a class but if I try to call the method using express inside a post method, and using it like follows the code works fine.**

```
var express = require('express'),
router = express.Router(),
config = require('config'),
Message = require('powerdrill').Message;

router.post('/welcome',function(req,res,next){
  message = new Message();
  message.apiKey(config.mandrillKey)
    .subject(req.body.subject)
    .template(req.body.template)
    .from(config.mandrilEmail)
    .to(req.body.to)
    .tag('complex')
    .globalMergeVar('VERIFY_EMAIL',req.body.linkVefifyEmail)
    .send(function(err, resp) 
      res.send(resp).end();
    });
});
```

Comment: It most likely has to do with your use of [strict mode](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strict.asp). In strict mode you need to define variables before assigning them, i.e. `let message` or `var message` rather than just `message`

Comment: Well I commented the line *strict mode and didn´t work. But I added var before message and it worked. 
Thanks!